# how to build in and build out a layer?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-animation

I want to build in a layer and build out it after 5 seconds. but I don't know how to assign the final value to the layer. my code is as following:

```
-(CABasicAnimation *) buildIn{
    CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"opacity"];
    animation.duration = 2.0f;
    [animation setFromValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0f]];
    [animation setToValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0f]];
    [animation setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut]];
    return animation;
}

-(CABasicAnimation *) buildOut{
    CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"opacity"];
    animation.duration = 2.0f;
    animation.beginTime = CACurrentMediaTime() + 5;
    [animation setFromValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0f]];
    [animation setToValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0f]];
    [animation setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut]];
    return animation;
}

- (IBAction)startAnimation:(id)sender {
    [self.textView.layer addAnimation:[self buildIn] forKey:@"transparent"];
    self.textView.layer.opacity = 1.0f;//I need to set the opacity to 1 after buildIn animation
    [self.textView.layer addAnimation:[self buildOut] forKey:@"transparent"];
    self.textView.layer.opacity = 0.0f;//ERROR: this is the final layer value, but I need to assign it after the build out animation, not here.
}
```

I think I can use a completion block to do it, but I can't find it.

Comment: maybe this answer will help you - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11515647/objective-c-cabasicanimation-applying-changes-after-animation

Comment: Can't you just use `[UIView animateWithDuration...` instead? It seems you're just animating the opacity on `self.textView`...

Comment: @jjv360 well, this just a sample. I need to use Core Animation.

Answer (score 0):

If you set a delegate on your `buildIn` animation, then when it is finished the `-animationDidStop:finished:` message will be sent to the delegate. Then you can start your `buildOut` animation.

[CAAnimation delegate reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CAAnimation_class/Introduction/Introduction.html)