# Create coloured circle based on value(360) or percentage(100%)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cashapelayer, caanimation

This code creating a complete circle but I want to create a circle based on value either 360 or percentage 100%. IF percentage is 56% I want 56% circle. Like this based on percentage/value, I want circle.

```
CAShapeLayer *circle = [CAShapeLayer layer];
circle.path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithArcCenter:CGPointMake(29, 29) radius:27 startAngle:-M_PI_2 endAngle:2 * M_PI - M_PI_2 clockwise:YES].CGPath;
circle.fillColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
circle.strokeColor = [UIColor greenColor].CGColor;
circle.lineWidth = 4;

CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"strokeEnd"];
animation.duration = 10;
animation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
animation.fromValue = @(0);
animation.toValue = @(1);
animation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear];
[circle addAnimation:animation forKey:@"drawCircleAnimation"];

[_colouredCircle.layer.sublayers makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperlayer)];
[_colouredCircle.layer addSublayer:circle];
```

Comment: @ Alladinian, yes you are right but, it's not stopped at **0.56**, after 10sec's it's creating complete circle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That means that your `toValue` should match your percentage.

In your case, `animation.toValue = @(0.56);` would end the stroke at 56% of the circle (`0...1` range).

[See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11515647/objective-c-cabasicanimation-applying-changes-after-animation) for information about keeping the final animated value after completion.

TLDR: You have to also update the model layer.

```
circle.strokeStart = 0;
circle.strokeEnd   = 0.56; // Your target value
...
// Your animation
```

Comment: already i tried but after 10sec its creating complete circle. Only animation will be stopped at **0.56**.

Comment: I want only that **0.56** circle

Comment: Please see the linked answer for this

Comment: I added this single line to my above code `animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;` . It's working. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this](https://github.com/stablekernel/STKSpinnerView) **circular progress bar** and set colour as you want to set at particular position.