# Spinning imageview animation

Tags: ios, swift

I want to spin a imageview for forever. I tried following code:

```
    UIView.animateWithDuration(3, animations: {
        self.loginLogo.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation((360 * CGFloat(M_PI)) / 360)
        }){ (finished) -> Void in
            self.rotateImage()
    }
```

But this is working for one time. My imageview is not spinning forever. How can I fix it?

Comment: You could take a look at this example code, that may help: https://github.com/rebello95/SizedSpinningImage

Comment: possible duplicate of [Spin UIImageView continuously](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7269076/spin-uiimageview-continuously)

Comment: It is not for swift.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to rotate your image forever you can do it this way:

```
func rotateViewLayer() {
    let rotateView = CABasicAnimation()

    rotateView.fromValue = 0.degreesToRadian
    rotateView.toValue = 360.degreesToRadian
    rotateView.duration = 1
    rotateView.repeatCount = Float.infinity
    rotateView.removedOnCompletion = false
    rotateView.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards
    rotateView.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear)
    imageView.layer.addAnimation(rotateView, forKey: "transform.rotation.z")
}
```

And here is your helper extension:

```
extension Int {
    var degreesToRadian : CGFloat {
        return CGFloat(self) * CGFloat(M_PI) / 180.0
    }
}
```

And you can refer [THIS](https://github.com/DharmeshKheni/Loading-View) sample project for more Info.

Answer (score 0):

use this on layer of your view

```
var myImageView:UIImageView?
    var rotation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.rotation")
    rotation.fromValue = 0.0
    rotation.toValue = 2*M_PI
    rotation.duration = 1.1
    rotation.repeatCount = Float.infinity
    myImageView?.layer.addAnimation(rotation, forKey: "Spin")
```

Comment: How to implement it to imageview?

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
func startAnimationWithDuration(duration:CGFloat)
    {
        var rotationAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.rotation.z")
        rotationAnimation.fromValue = 0
        rotationAnimation.toValue = 2 * M_PI
        rotationAnimation.duration = NSTimeInterval(duration)
        rotationAnimation.repeatCount = 1000.0 //some large value
        imageView.layer.addAnimation(rotationAnimation, forKey: "spin")
    }
```